# Flutter: How can I get my stream to show updated value without having to reload the page?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have user time spent on app from firebase in seconds, I then convert it into hours, min and sec, and want to display to the user, I'm using streams but it will not update when there is a new value. I have to reload the page or go to a different page then come back to see the updated value. What am I doing wrong?

```
late Stream<String> testStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      setState(() {
        testStream = printDuration();
      });
    });    
  }
  

  Stream<String>printDuration() async*{
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
          (event) => print("current data: ${event.data()!['timeActive']}"),
          onError: (error) => print("Listen failed: $error"),
        );

    Duration duration = Duration(seconds: loggedInUser.timeActive!);
    String? data = loggedInUser.timeActive.toString();
     print('###');
    print(data);
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    String _getData = "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
    print(_getData);
        yield _getData; 
}
```

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
  stream: testStream,
  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
      //userDocument['timeActive'];
      return Center(
        child: Text(snapshot.data,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff516395),
            fontSize: 26.0,
            letterSpacing: 2.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Text('0',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff516395),
            fontSize: 30.0,
            letterSpacing: 2.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ));
    }
  }),
)
```

Comment: In short: use `onSnapshot` instead of `get`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Im getting the following error ```The method 'onSnapshot' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'onSnapshot'.```

With the code ```FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .onSnapshot()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      });
    });```

Comment: Ah, on Flutter it's called `snapshots()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart

Comment: Thanks, I have made that change but it still does not refresh the UI when there is a new value, I have to navigate to another page, then come back to see the updated result.

Comment: I recommend updating the code in your question to show what you've done with the `snapshots` stream. It's also more likely that someone can help if you show the steps you've taken yourself to debug the problem. For example: if you put a breakpoint in the `listen` method and run in a debugger, does it reach that?

Comment: Changes have been made! The streambuilder works fine, i just want the UI to data the most recent data while user is on the page and now have to navigate to a different page and come back to see the updated value